# Show that the usual action of SL2(Z) (the group of 2×2 integer matrices with determinant 1 ) on R2 induces a transitive action of SL2(Z) on S .

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-actions

Let $S$ be the set of all lines in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ that pass through the origin and have either rational or
infinite slope. Show that the usual action of $SL_{2}(\mathbf{Z})$ (the group of $2 \times 2$ integer matrices
with determinant $1$) on $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ induces a transitive action of $SL_{2}(\mathbf{Z})$ on $S$.

**My Attempt**: We need to construct $A\in SL_{2}(\mathbf{Z})$ such that $A\begin{pmatrix}
 1\\p
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\q
\end{pmatrix}$ for distinct $p,q \in \mathbf{Q}$. But I am not able to construct $A$, give some Hints.

Comment: Show that $(a,b)$ can be mapped to $(c,d)$ with $|c| + |d| < |a| + |b|$ and use an inductive argument. For example, if $a,b>0$ and $a>b$ then map $(a, b)$ to $(a-b ,b)$. (I'm writing vectors as row vectors.)

Comment: Mathjax works in the title section, too, don't you know?

Comment: You need to know a bit of number theory, namely: if $a,b$ are coprime integers then there are integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Put some of these facts together.

- $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{Z}\curvearrowright S$ transitively iff $S$ is an orbit, say of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}=\mathrm{span}\{(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix})\}$.
- A line of slope $m=\frac{a}{b}$ is the span of $(\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix})$.
- Every rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ has a reduced form where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
- Bezout's theorem for pairs of coprime integers.

Comment: Thank you very much, consider $q = \frac{a}{b}$, with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then there exist $x,y\in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $ax+by = 1$, so our required matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
a&-y\\b&x
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
a&-y\\b&x
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a\\b
\end{pmatrix}$.